# How can I eliminate $x_1$ from my two ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

How can I get *Mathematica* to eliminate $x_1$ in the equations in the first box to achieve the equation in the second box？

[image: eguations.png]

My code:

```
Reduce[{
  f[t] - k[1] x[1] - B[1] D[x[2], t] - B[3] D[x[1] - x[2], t] == m[1] D[x[1], {t, 2}],
  B[3] D[x[1] - x[2], t] - B[2] D[x[2], t] - k[2] x[2] == m[2] D[x[2], {t, 2}]},
  {f[t], k[1], k[2], x[2], t, B[1], B[2], B[3], m[1], m[2]}]
```

*Mathematica*' s answer:

> ```
> (x[1] == 0 && f[t] == 0 && k[2] == 0) || (x[1] == 0 && f[t] == 0 && 
>    x[2] == 0) || (x[1] != 0 && k[1] == f[t]/x[1] && 
>    k[2] == 0) || (x[1] != 0 && k[1] == f[t]/x[1] && x[2] == 0)
> ```

Comment: Upvoting in part to counter the weight of existing votes. Note sure why this is getting the downvotes though. User might be new to mathematica but it's far from a trivial problem under consideration (at least, for me it's far).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I agree. While somewhat of a duplicate (as you point out), it isn't a simple problem and should be addressed. The OP does have simple errors in his code, but those are addressable and not directly related to the underlying issue. So, I'm upvoting, also.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think most of the downvotes were cast for the [first version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/29197/1) of this post... seems appropriate in that context :)

Comment: @rm -rf Ah, I see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) You need to make the functions that depend on `t` explicit.

(2) You need to do differential elimination. This involves prolonging (taking derivatives). More on this below.

(3) This question, while perfectly reasonable, is something of a duplicate (though the earlier variants might not be so easy to locate in MSE). They are [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/eliminate-doesnt-work-in-mathematica) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9765/differentiating-an-unknown-solution-to-a-pde). [Note to moderators: given the relative obscurity of the prior posts I think it's fine to keep this question as well.]

I show a bare-bones version for your equations. In general one would use a loop to iterate prolongations interspersed with projections, until obtaining a result that fully eliminates all derivatives one is trying to remove.

```
eqs = {f[t] - k1 x1[t] - B1 D[x2[t], t] - B3 D[x1[t] - x2[t], t] == 
    m1 D[x1[t], {t, 2}], 
   B3 D[x1[t] - x2[t], t] - B2 D[x2[t], t] - k2 x2[t] == 
    m2 D[x2[t], {t, 2}]};

eqs2 = Join[eqs, D[eqs, t]];
eqs3 = Join[eqs2, D[eqs, {t, 2}]];

Eliminate[eqs3, {x1[t], D[x1[t], t], D[x1[t], {t, 2}], 
  D[x1[t], {t, 3}], D[x1[t], {t, 4}]}]

(* Out[19]= k1*k2*x2[t] + B2*k1*Derivative[1][x2][t] + 
     B3*k1*Derivative[1][x2][t] + B3*k2*Derivative[1][x2][t] + 
     B1*B3*Derivative[2][x2][t] + B2*B3*Derivative[2][x2][t] + 
     k2*m1*Derivative[2][x2][t] + k1*m2*Derivative[2][x2][t] + 
     B2*m1*Derivative[3][x2][t] + B3*m1*Derivative[3][x2][t] + 
     B3*m2*Derivative[3][x2][t] + m1*m2*Derivative[4][x2][t] == 
   B3*Derivative[1][f][t] *)
```

Comment: I would also run `Collect[%, Derivative[_][_][t]]` on the result to simplify it.